# What does the three dots in the parameter list of a function mean?

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I came across a function definition like:

```
char* abc(char *f, ...)
{
}
```

What do the three dots mean?

Comment: thanks all for quick response... this community is just awsome..

Answer (score 52, accepted):

These type of functions are called ***variadic functions*** ([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function)). They use ellipses (i.e., three dots) to indicate that there is a variable number of arguments that the function can process. One place you've probably used such functions (perhaps without realising) is with the various `printf` functions, for example (from the ISO standard):

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

The ellipses allow you to create functions where the number of parameters are not known beforehand, and you can use `stdargs.h` functions (`va_start`, `va_arg` and `va_end`) to get the specific arguments.

You do have to know the *types* of the arguments you extract and have some way of deciding when you're done. The `printf` functions do this with the format string (for both types and count), while my example code below always assumes `const char *` as the type with a sentinel value `NULL` to decide completion.

This link [here](http://www.eskimo.com/%7Escs/cclass/int/sx11b.html) has a good treatise on the use of variable argument lists in `printf`.

---

As an example, the following program contains a function `outStrings()`, that allows you to print an arbitrary number of strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void outStrings(const char *strFirst, ...) {
    // First argument handled specially.

    printf("%s", strFirst);
    va_list pArg;
    va_start(pArg, strFirst);

    // Just get and process each string until NULL given.

    const char *strNext = va_arg(pArg, const char *);
    while (strNext != NULL) {
        printf("%s", strNext);
        strNext = va_arg(pArg, const char *);
    }

    // Finalise processing.

    va_end(pArg);
}

int main(void) {
    char *name = "paxdiablo";
    outStrings("Hello, ", name, ", I hope you're feeling well today.\n", NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Wikipedia on [vararg functions in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varargs#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D).

Answer (score 12):

They are called an elipsis and they mean that the function can take an indeterminate number of parameters. Your function can probably be called like this:

```
abc( "foo", 0 );
abc( "foo", "bar", 0 );
```

There needs to be a way of indicating the end of the list. This can be done by using the first parameter, as ion a printf(0 format string, or by a special terminator, zero in the example above.

Functions with a variable number of parameters are considered bad form in C++, as no type checking or user defined conversions can be performed on the parameters.

Answer (score 5):

This is what is called a varargs function or a variable argument function in C.

One you'll probably recognise is printf.