# what does ... means inside function parameter (const char *value, ...)

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about a function definition (three dots in parameters..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599744/question-about-a-function-definition-three-dots-in-parameters)

I'm new to c++, what is the meaning of the ... (triple dot) inside the method or function

sample

```
void strArr::set(const char *value, ...) {
     // some code here
}
```

Comment: Take note that variadic templates are a better choice if available.

Comment: oh thanks i didn't seen this.

Answer (score 2):

It's a way to express a variable number of arguments, used to be called va_args or [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) function.

Take a look [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/va_arg/) to learn about them in C++, they do exist in other programming languages though, since it's just a generic concept.

Answer (score 1):

That's a variadic function, it can take any number of parameters (more than 1 in this case).

Same principle as `printf` and others:

```
printf("%d", 1);
printf("%d%d%d", 1,1,1);
printf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", 1,1,1,1,1,1);
```

These aren't overloads, but the same function taking a variable number of arguments.