# what's ... for function parameter?

Tags: c++, c, function, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question about a function definition (three dots in parameters..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599744/question-about-a-function-definition-three-dots-in-parameters)

I'd like to call a function which looks like

```
  void        (*CallVoidMethod)(JNIEnv*, jobject, jmethodID, ...);
```

what's the '...' ?

How do I call this function?

Comment: wow negative vote madness..  So what should I do when I realize my question is duplicate of something?

Answer (score 6):

It's a function with a variable amount of arguments, like `printf`.

[Here](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html) you can find a small tutorial for those functions. They are also called "varargs" functions.